# How to add WPS to a QGIS Web Client?

Tags: wps, qgis-web-client

I have managed to work the QGIS Web Client on my server with the basic buttons and functions.

Now I would like to add "extra" geoprocessing tasks (for example create buffer), based on WPS.

I understand how to add new button to the QGIS Web Client toolbar by the Customizations.js file, but I can not find any working example about how to define the button's function as a geoprocessing task, based on a public WPS (for example Zoo project's WPS capabilities, which I can use in QGIS Desktop).

Is it possible to do? If yes, could you please help me with the basics or show me a working example and code behind it?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try to integrate the ZOO-Client which is a WPS JavaScript Client able to communicate with servers implementing both version 1.0.0 and 2.0.0. You can have more information from [the official documentation](http://zoo-project.org/docs/client/) and take a look at [the demos](http://zoo-project.org/new/Resources/Examples).